# Canadian visiting Japan

Tags: japan, canadian-citizens

I’m a Canadian citizen and I want to visit my girlfriend in Japan. Is Japanese immigration strict compared to the US? I also wonder if my reason for visiting (to visit my girlfriend) would be a problem.

I’m only staying for 1 month. I have my return ticket ready, a place to stay, a $4500 money and a credit card, and also a proof of my work here in Canada in case they ask me.

Comment: Check out https://www.ca.emb-japan.go.jp/itpr_en/visa_FAQ.html#:~:text=Canadians%20who%20enter%20Japan%20as,any%20income%20while%20in%20Japan. It looks like you can stay for 90 days as a Canadian citizen and you don't even need a visa

Comment: With the visa waiver, Japan's immigration probably won't even ask you why you're visiting, let alone for proof of funds, etc.

Comment: AFAIK, all foreigners are fingerprinted upon entering Japan, don't be surprised. Other than that, just make sure you're not carrying anything illegal or suspicious (drugs, items given to you by strangers...), and you'll be fine.

Comment: Japanese immigration almost never ask a question at all, so you'll be fine

Answer (score 3):

In the 50+ times I've been to Japan, I have never been asked the purpose of my visit at Immigration. Customs (luggage inspection) officers sometimes did. But they were more interested in business people with potentially samples of alcohol, meds, food, etc.